# Help me out in finding the problem in my given MATLAB code of Rectangular Contour Algorithm(RCA)

Tags: matlab, equalization, fading-channel

I am implementing the Rectangular Contour Algorithm (RCA) used for blind channel equalization on 32 Rectangular QAM Signal, polluted with noise and channel effects. It is described in:

> [*Khan Q.* - Two Novel Blind Equalization Algorithms for Rectangular
>   Quadrature Amplitude Modulation
>   Constellations](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7790854)

I am not achieving reduction in the ISI value in dB as the iterations increases. When I use exact value of $\mu$ as given in research paper it diverges giving equalizer tap weights to `NaN` and everything goes to `NaN`. But decreasing the step size $\mu$ it becomes stable, whilst ISI increases instead of decreases.

Here is my MATLAB Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all
m = 32;                                     
SNR = 30;
ITERATIONS=5000;
RUNS= 3;
%h=[-0.005-j*0.004 0.009+j*0.030 -0.024-j*0.104 0.854+j*0.520 -0.218+j*0.273 0.049-j*0.074 -0.016+j*0.020];


h=randn(1,7)+i*randn(1,7);
%h=h/norm(h);

N =length(h);                                      %equalizer length
M =32;
x = 0:M-1;
y = modulate(modem.qammod(M),x);
%32 rect qam
 A1 = [-7 7 -7 7 real(y(5:28)) 7 -7 7 -7]';
 B1 = [-3 -3 3 3 imag(y(5:28)) -1 -1 1 1]';
Y1=A1+j*B1;
 %scatterplot(Y1)
QAM = Y1';
Es = mean(abs(QAM).^2);                     % Average Signal energy
S=floor((N-1)/2);


nm = N-1;
Res_ISI = zeros(1,ITERATIONS);
MSEn = zeros(1,ITERATIONS);
bn=zeros(1,ITERATIONS);
%h = h./sqrt(sum(abs(h).^2));
R = length(h)-1;
cl = length(h)-1;
varn = Es*10^(-SNR/10);
stdn=sqrt(varn);
stdn_by_2 = stdn/sqrt(2);


for runs=1:RUNS
    R_S=[];
    E_O=[];
    W=zeros(N,1);
    W(S,1)=1;
    C = zeros(N,1);
    X = zeros(cl+1,1);
    disp(['Run = ' num2str(runs)]);
    for i = 1:ITERATIONS
        x = QAM(ceil(rand*m));
        X = [x; X(1:cl,1)];
        Ns = (randn+j*randn)*stdn_by_2;
        c = h*X + Ns;
        C = [c ; C(1:nm,1)];
        YY = transpose(W)*C;%Equalizer Output
        E_O=[YY E_O];
        R_S=[c R_S];


%RECT Contour Implementation        
mu = 1e-15;
A=7;
B=3;
R_rect=1.7927;%32 RQAM 
P=1;
YR=real(YY);
YI=imag(YY);
T1=B*YR+A*YI;
T2=B*YR-A*YI;
S1=sign(T1);
S2=sign(T2);
S3=A*YR-A*YI;

%Del Jrect Equation
del_Jrect=((abs(T1)+abs(T2)).^P-(abs(A*B)*R_rect).^P).*((abs(T1)+abs(T2)).^(P-1)).*((B*S1+B*S3)+i*(A*S1-A*S2));
del_Jrect=del_Jrect.*conj(C);
%Taps Update Equation
W=W-(mu*del_Jrect);   


TA=abs((h.*conj(W)')).^2;
TB=max(TA);
res_isi(1,i)=(sum(TA)-TB)/TB;
    end
    Res_ISI = Res_ISI+res_isi;
%    MSEn = MSEn+mse;
 scatterplot(R_S);
 %scatterplot(filter(W,1,R_S));
end
% end

Res_ISI=Res_ISI/runs;

%____________________________________________________________
 figure;
 plot(10*log10(abs(smooth(Res_ISI,100))));grid on;
ylabel('ISI(dB)'); xlabel('Iterations');
```

Comment: Please include your code inline (not as pictures) with the proper formatting. Also, include a reference or two to the algorithm's description.

Comment: I'm closing this question because there is no effort to paste the code.

Comment: Dear jojek the code was too lengthy to put in the body section as I have already tried to put it in the body section but it was not copied properly from the software.

Comment: Please also guide me how to put code as inline?

Comment: I have put the code as inline.pls open my question to public.

Comment: Dear MBaz  The algortihm is implemented from this research paper:                                   ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7790854/